# Query with mix of data from different but related object

Tags: apex

I have two objects Opportunity and approval__c that are related.
One Opportunity can have multiple approval_c.

I would like for each opportunity that have an Approval to return a list containing a mix of Opportunity data and Last approval Data.

So I planned to do two list 1 for the Opportunity, one for the Last approval and merge them together.
However I am not sure on how to get the data about the last approval.

my code looks like:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Object> approvalTableData(){
        List<Object> FinalList = new List<Object>();
        List<AggregateResult> OppList = [SELECT Opportunity__r.Id  FROM Approval__c 
                                     WHERE (Type__c = 'Investment_Committee' OR Type__c = 'Pre_IC')
                                     AND Status__c != Null
                                     AND CALENDAR_YEAR(Date__c) = 2021
                                     GROUP BY Opportunity__r.Id];
        
        for(AggregateResult item: OppList){
            List<Opportunity> OppData = [SELECT Id, Name, StageName
                                         FROM Opportunity
                                         WHERE Id = :item.Id];
            
            List<AggregateResult> LastApproval = [SELECT max(date__c) FROM Approval__c GROUP BY Opportunity__c];
            system.debug(LastApproval);
            
            List<Approval__c>ApprovalList = [SELECT Id, Status__c, date__c 
                                             FROM Approval__c 
                                             WHERE Opportunity__r.id = :item.Id 
                                             and Type__c = 'Pre_IC'
                                             ];
            system.debug(ApprovalList);
        }
        
        
        
        
        return OppList;
        
    }
```

It looks like a very bad practice, but I am kinda lost could you please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge multiple List from queries](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346821/merge-multiple-list-from-queries)

Comment: looks like it's a duplicate of your question.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/346839/3813.

Comment: Kind of... Discard my code. how would you design the code if you had to do it from scratch ? with best practices ?
I need to learn about the wrapper class I am kind of lost right now ;)

Comment: np, I have added the pseudo-code in the answer section in the last post. it follows the best practice. I will refine my answer or maybe written separately on usage or best practices of wrappers. Have a look at this and its a good start with design and best practise.https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346821/merge-multiple-list-from-queries

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/346839/3813 added details and explanation as requested